# How to validate dynamic table when using ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

I am trying to add jQuery validation to the dynamic table in my application. Here is my code .

```
    <table border="1px" id="table">
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=text name="fname_new[0]" class="table_input" /></td>
            <td><input type=text name="lname_new[0]" class="table_input" /></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
  <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

On clicking on add button I am adding the row by jquery

```
  $("#AddLine").click(function () {
  var row = "<tr><td><input name=fname_new[" + num_rows + "] type=text class='table_input' /></td><td><input name=lname_new[" + num_rows + "]type=text class='table_input' /></td></tr>";
      $("#table").append(row);
            num_rows++;
    });
```

Here I am submitting the form using ajax post. The form is submitted like this

```
<input type="button" id="savebutton" value="save'/>
```

On clicking the button the form is posted like this

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("", "MyCOntroller")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formdata,
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                $('#UserMessage').html(response.UserMsg);

            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        });
```

I want to validate the dynamic table using jQuery, Can someone please tell me how to validate before posting through ajax.

Comment: Validate what? The the textbox has a value? That it matches a regex?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various things. Such as what do you want to validate? What framework are you using?

If, for example, you want to validate that a value must be entered, you need to add an attribute to the input: `data-val-required="The xxxxx field is required"`. Then before calling your ajax function check that the data is valid using `if ($('#yourFormId').valid())`. You will also need a data validation message display which I can't currently remember the syntax for.

There are various things that can be validated rather than just that a field is required. You should look up jQuery validation as there I already plenty of information that is very easy to find.

If you are using ASP.Net MVC, then you should be looking at unobtrusive validation. You can then add data annotations to your models such as [Required] and the necessary attributes will be automatically put in when using Html.EditorFor, etc. Again, this is very easy to find information on.